# Swift textfield and value validation

Tags: swift, uitextfield

This seems easy but I'm not able to find a solution searching the web. I have the following variables that I need to validate. If the validation is not correct then I want the app to stop and return to the storyboard.

```
  let mortgageTerm = Double(mortgageTermLabel.text!)
  let name 
  let mtgCashback = Double(casbackRecieved.text!)
  let mtgBalance = Double(mortgageBalance.text!)
  let rate = Double(currentRate.text!)
```

- Mortgage term needs to be a value greater than 6 and less than or equal to 60
- Mortgage balance needs to be greater than 10,000
- The rate should be greater than 1 but less than 10

And a value MUST be selected for the control `@IBOutlet weak var lenderName: UITextField!` - I a customer picker that gives the user options to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `guard let` Here is an example

```
guard let mortgage = Double(mortgageTermLabel.text!) , mortgage > 6 && mortgage <= 60 else {return}
```

Moreover, you can display a friendly alert message just before the return in this way

```
guard let mortgage = Double(mortgageTermLabel.text!) , mortgage > 6 && mortgage <= 60 else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "blah", message: "blah blah", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}

guard let balance = Double(mortgageBalance.text!) , balance > 10000 else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "blah", message: "blah blah", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}

guard let date = YourDate , date < Date() else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "blah", message: "blah blah", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

Comment: You don't need `guard let`. `if let` is just as valid.

Comment: @rmaddy From my understanding, the reason they invented guard let is to conform the English writting. So in English, `guard let` is like saying that I want my variable to meet some requirement, if something is not met, return immediately. If you use `if let`, you need to do the next check inside and then have to do the `return` in the else and that is just not like English.

Comment: I didn't say `guard let` was wrong. You stated it was "needed" as if it was the only solution. I'm simply pointing out that there is another valid option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How would I return a pop op message pointing the user to the error... Example message: the term is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am not understanding how to add the alerts to the specific guard statement. And how would I use a guard statement to check that a date is not greater than today

Comment: @KevinProctor Update. For more questions, please create another question. This current question should already be answered. Thank you :)